# Calculating the error in the solution of a system of ODEs

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, warning-messages

I have solved system of ODEs by using `NDSolve`. I want to calculate the error of the solutions. So far I have calculated error by plotting results of each equation.

1. Is what I'm doing the correct way to obtain the error for my problem?
2. I am not sure the results I am getting are accurate enough. If not, then kindly suggest some other way to calculate the error.

My code for solving the system of ODEs

```
s = 
  NDSolve[
    {x''[t] == -(1/2)*y[t]*x'[t], y''[t] == x'[t], 
     x'[0] == -1 + x[0], y[0] == 0, x[10] == 0, y'[10] == 0}, 
    {x, y}, {t, 20}]
```

I am examining the error for the 1st equation with

```
Plot[(x''[t] + (1/2)*y[t]*x'[t]) /. s, {t, 1, 10}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]
```

[image]

and for the 2nd equation

```
Plot[(y''[t] + x'[t]) /. s, {t, 1, 10}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]
```

[image]

Comment: Your sign is incorrect for the second one. it should be `y''[t] - x'[t]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two sources of error to investigate, the error in the steps and the interpolation error.

First, to explore the error, I usually set up some variables to make it easier:

```
ode = {x''[t] == -(1/2)*y[t]*x'[t], y''[t] == x'[t]};
bcs = {x'[0] == -1 + x[0], y[0] == 0, x[10] == 0, y'[10] == 0};
residuals = ode /. Equal -> Subtract;
{s} = NDSolve[{ode, bcs}, {x, y}, {t, 20}]
```

I separate the `ode` from the initial/boundary conditions `bcs`.  The `residuals` can be computed directly from `ode`, which prevents transcription errors and maintenance errors if `ode` is changed.

*[Side note: The assignment `{s} = NDSolve[..]` is my peculiarity. Its purpose is to perform a simple check on the solution. See end for discussion.]*

We can use `ListPlot`/`ListLogPlot` to plot the steps and `Plot`/`LogPlot` for the interpolating functions. I usually use a log-plot because the error often exhibits a range of several orders of magnitude.  I sometimes use a regular plot of [`RealExponent[residuals]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RealExponent.html), which is equivalent to a log-plot of `Abs[residuals]`.

#### Error at the steps

The times of the steps can be obtained with either of these:

```
x["Coordinates"] /. s
x["Grid"] /. s
```

They are structured lists. To get flat list of the times, use [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html).  *[Note that for a PDE, which has a domain of more than one dimension, these lists are structured differently, and you cannot simply use `Flatten`.]*

The code

```
residuals /. t -> x["Coordinates"] /. s
```

first replaces `t` by a list `{{t1, t2,...}}`, and then replaces `x` and `y` by their [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html) solutions.
This works because `InterpolatingFunction` threads over lists as do the basic arithmetic operations. Thus the following yields a plot of the `residuals` at the steps by step number.

```
ListPlot[
 RealExponent[Flatten /@ (residuals /. t -> x["Coordinates"] /. s)],
 Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want to plot the `residuals` versus `t`, it's somewhat somewhat simpler to process each residual separately and list the ordered pairs using `Table`:

```
With[{data = {
    Table[{t, Abs@residuals[[1]]} /. s, {t, x["Coordinates"] /. s // Flatten}],
    Table[{t, Abs@residuals[[2]]} /. s, {t, x["Coordinates"] /. s // Flatten}]}},
 ListLogPlot[
  data,
  Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The plot could be done with `RealExponent` and `ListPlot` as in the previous one, but I thought I'd show the variant with `LogPlot` and `Abs`.
The spike at `t == 10` is probably due to `NDSolve` choosing `t == 10` as the starting time for the initial condition in the shooting method it uses to solve the BVP.

#### Error of the interpolation

Dealing with the interpolations is easier.  What we see below is that the error between the steps is greater.  Plotting with some transparency makes it easier to examine both residuals.

```
Plot[RealExponent[residuals /. s] // Evaluate,
 {t, 0, 20}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.75], Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The deep spikes between the steps are typical of Hermite cubic interpolation.  The plot below is typical of the residuals between steps:

```
With[{step = 100},
 Plot[residuals /. s // Evaluate, 
  Evaluate@Flatten[{t, (x["Grid"] /. s)[[{step, step + 1}]]}], 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.75], Frame -> True]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One can infer that the spikes are where each residual crosses zero, as well as smaller ones at the steps themselves (all of which may by limited by the resolution of the plot).

#### Improving the error

By default, `NDSolve` usually returns a Hermite piecewise cubic interpolation of the steps

```
{sALL} = NDSolve[{ode, ics},    (* same solution as `s`, but with "dense output" *)
  {x, y}, {t, 20}, 
  InterpolationOrder -> All]

{sRK} = NDSolve[{ode, ics},      (* different method, for the sake of comparison *)
  {x, y}, {t, 20}, 
  Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta", InterpolationOrder -> All]
```

From below, one can see that the dense outputs take much more memory, even though `sALL` has the same steps as `s` and `sRK` has many fewer steps.

```
Length /@ (x["Grid"] /. {s, sALL, sRK})  (* number of steps *)
ByteCount /@ {s, sALL, sRK}              (* memory used by the solution *)
(*
  {112, 112, 37}
  {12024, 153352, 70024}
*)
```

The three solution use three different methods of interpolation.

```
x["InterpolationMethod"] /. {s, sALL, sRK}
(*  {"Hermite", "Local Taylor series", "Chebyshev"}  *)
```

If you look at the error at the steps as above, you will see that for `s` and `sALL`, they are exactly the same.  The error for `sRK` turns out to be much better, but it's using a different method.  What's more important is that the dense output solutions have much less error ***between*** the steps.

```
Plot[
 Join[
   RealExponent[residuals /. s],
   RealExponent[residuals /. sALL],
   RealExponent[residuals /. sRK]] // Evaluate,
 {t, 0, 20},
 PlotStyle ->
  {Opacity[0.4], Opacity[0.4], Opacity[0.6], Opacity[0.6], Opacity[0.8], Opacity[0.8]},
 PlotLegends -> {"s[[1]]", "s[[2]]", "sALL[[1]]", "sALL[[2]]", "sRK[[1]]", "sRK[[2]]"},
 Epilog -> {Red, Point@Thread[{Flatten[x@"Grid" /. sRK], -17}]}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One can see that the `residuals` for `sALL` are about two orders of magnitude small. For `sRK`, they are much smaller than that. Note for `sRK` there are several spikes between each step. This is typical of collocation methods, which interpolate the `ode` at several points; the solution is based on the corresponding interpolating polynomial.  The residual at a typical step may look like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One can see that the dense output improves accuracy considerably.  The question each user has to answer, is what accuracy is sufficient? When is the dense output worth it?

#### Checking `NDSolve`'s notion of error

*Mathematica* has a somewhat more complicated measure of error to handle the fact that as a solution gets closer to zero it gets harder to achieve a [`PrecisionGoal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrecisionGoal.html); in such circumstance, the [`AccuracyGoal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AccuracyGoal.html) becomes dominant.  See the tutorial [Norms in NDSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveVectorNorm.html).

The error norm is scaled so that a value below one indicates that the `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal` have been met.

```
svn = NDSolve`ScaledVectorNorm[Infinity, 10.^(-MachinePrecision/2) {1, 1}];
Max@ Map[
 svn[residuals,
     {x''[t], y''[t]} /. First@Solve[ode, {x''[t], y''[t]}]] /. s /. t -> # &, 
 Flatten[x["Coordinates"] /. s]
 ]
(*  0.467073  *)
```

So the worst step is comfortably within the margin of error.

---

*[Re: The assignment `{s} = NDSolve[..]`. It performs a simple check on the solution.
`NDSolve` returns a list of solutions, the length of which list depends on the degree of the system (of the highest order derivatives). Note each solution is itself a list of functions for each dependent variable.  For a quasilinear system such as `ode` in the OP's case, the number of solutions will be `1`.  An assignment of the form `{s} = NDSolve[..]` will fail if the `ode` is not quasilinear or if `NDSolve` fails.  The examples in the document apply `First`, either to `First[s]` if `s = NDSolve[..]`, or `s = First@NDSolve[..]`. Such code does not fail if `ode` has multiple solutions; instead, it throws away any solutions after the first. To unwittingly throw them away is a serious error, which `{s} = NDSolve[..]` detects. The annoying thing about my way is that when there are multiple solutions, they are discarded, although they can be retrieved with `%`, if `$HistoryLength` is greater than zero.  Another way that preserves a multiple solution would be the assignments `{s} = s = NDSolve[..]`. But sometimes I only want to overwrite `s` if `NDSolve` returns a solution.]*

Comment: It might be interesting to look at the `InterpolatingFunction[]` returned with either of the settings `Method -> "Extrapolation"` or `Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"`.

Comment: @J.M. They produce (identical) solutions with fewer steps (31) than `sRK` (37) and [residuals that are between those of `s` and `sRK`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VwbaD.png).  The dense output is stored as piecewise Chebyshev series. (Should it be included? I thought it was getting overwhelming. Drat, just noticed another typo....)

Comment: @MichaelE2. This detailed explanation helped me a lot for calculating the error and as you have also given the error comparison obtained from three different methods. So now I solved my problem with ExplicitRK method  which  greatly reduces the error.

Comment: @Michael, that's up to you; the reason why I brought those up is that I've found that it often surprises people that Bulirsch-Stoer is often able to take very long steps, until I gently remind that those long steps were created from extrapolating over a sequence of increasingly finer steps. (And after all, Bulirsch-Stoer is effectively equivalent to an RK method of very high order.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for such a detailed and wonderful answer.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Can you please explain this part of code `residuals = ode /. Equal -> Subtract`?

Comment: @MMM It replaces all instances of `Equal` with `Subtract`.  So if you have `a == b`, which is the typeset form of `Equal[a, b]`, it becomes `Subtract[a, b]`, which evaluates to `a - b`.  In short, it gives the difference between the left-hand and right-hand sides of each equation in `ode`.  Some people prefer `Subtract @@@ ode`, which replaces the head of each element in `ode` with `Subtract`; if `ode` is a list of equations as in this case, it has the same effect.