# Comparing result of NDSolve to Coefficient Plug-in using Runge-Kutta-Fehlberg

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I use Mathematica's built-in method:

```
s1 = NDSolve[{x1'[t] == x2[t], 
x2'[t] == -5 x2[t] - 44 y1[t] - 0.5 x1[t] y1[t] + Sin[5 t], 
y1'[t] == y2[t], 
y2'[t] == -3 y2[t] - 2 x2[t] + x1[t] y1[t]^2 + Cos[5 t], 
x1[0] == 0.1, x2[0] == 0.02, y1[0] == 0.2, y2[0] == 0.01}, {x1, 
x2, y1, y2}, {t, 20}];
```

I then plot the results and all looks good:

```
Plot[Evaluate[{x1[t], x2[t], y1[t], y2[t]} /. First[s1]], {t, 0, 20}, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed["x1[t],x2[t],x3[t],x4[t]", Below], PlotRange -> All]
```

Now, I want to use a Runga-Kutta-Fehlberg [*Coefficient Plug-in*](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveExplicitRungeKutta.html) using the documented example. We define the plug-in paramters

```
Fehlbergamat = {{1/4}, {3/32, 9/32}, {1932/2197, -7200/2197, 
7296/2197}, {439/216, -8, 3680/513, -845/4104}, {-8/27, 
2, -3544/2565, 1859/4104, -11/40}};
Fehlbergbvec = {25/216, 0, 1408/2565, 2197/4104, -1/5, 0};
Fehlbergcvec = {1/4, 3/8, 12/13, 1, 1/2};
Fehlbergevec = {-1/360, 0, 128/4275, 2197/75240, -1/50, -2/55};
FehlbergCoefficients[4, p_] := 
 N[{Fehlbergamat, Fehlbergbvec, Fehlbergcvec, Fehlbergevec}, p];

Fehlberg45 = {"ExplicitRungeKutta", 
   "Coefficients" -> FehlbergCoefficients, "DifferenceOrder" -> 4, 
   "EmbeddedDifferenceOrder" -> 5, "StiffnessTest" -> False};
```

We then call NDSolve using this plug-in:

```
 s2 = NDSolve[{x1'[t] == x2[t], 
x2'[t] == -5 x2[t] - 44 y1[t] - 0.5 x1[t] y1[t] + Sin[5 t], 
y1'[t] == y2[t], 
y2'[t] == -3 y2[t] - 2 x2[t] + x1[t] y1[t]^2 + Cos[5 t], 
x1[0] == 0.1, x2[0] == 0.02, y1[0] == 0.2, y2[0] == 0.01}, {x1, 
x2, y1, y2}, {t, 20}, Method -> Fehlberg45];
```

I compared the Mathematica output with this plug-in using a plot of the results, for example

```
Plot[Evaluate[{x1[t], x2[t], y1[t], y2[t]} /. First[s2]], {t, 0, 20}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed["x1[t],x2[t],x3[t],x4[t]", Below], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

It runs, but when I plot or compare numerical values to Mathematica, the results look identical, thus I am not sure it is working properly. Is there a way to check that indeed the Fehlberg plug-in method is working properly?

Note: this is only tangentially related to this excellent answer [Calculating the error in the solution of a system of ODEs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121824/calculating-the-error-in-the-solution-of-a-system-of-odes), but compare that answer to this one - they are very different.

Comment: You can add a `Sow[]`to the right hand side of `FehlbergCoefficients[]` and wrap the `NDSolve`call in `Reap` to check if `FehlbergCoefficients[]` got called. You can also give it `\[Rho]` as parameter to see with whch arguments it got called. Also have a look at `EvaluationMonitor` in the documentation. This might help to get a look into the internal calls of `NDSolve`

Comment: Just saw the documentation on [StepMonitor](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StepMonitor.html) also has great examples (see the Applications section).

Comment: If you use `StepDataPlot[]` to look at the steps taken, you'll see that the behavior of the default multistep method is markedly different from the Fehlberg method. That at least tells us that the default is not being used in the second case.

Comment: The easiest way to see the difference between the default method and Fehlberg method is to check `Plot[Evaluate[MapThread[#[t] - #2@t &, #[[1, All, -1]] & /@ {s1, s2}]], {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ways to get information about an ODE solution `sol = NDSolve[..., {x,..}, {t, a, b}]`:

- Steps:

  - `x["Grid"] /. sol`
  - `x["Coordinates"] /. sol`
  - `Reap[NDSolve[..., StepMonitor :> Sow[t]]`
- Method:

  - `` Reap[NDSolve[..., MethodMonitor :> Sow[NDSolve`Self]] ``
  - `` Trace[NDSolve[...], NDSolve`InitializeMethod[__], TraceInternal -> True] ``
- Evaluations:

  - `Reap[NDSolve[..., EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[t]]`

Example (OP's but with a shorter interval of integration):

```
Block[{nstep = 0, neval = 0},
  {sol2, {steps2, methods2, eval2}} = 
   Reap[NDSolve[{x1'[t] == x2[t], 
      x2'[t] == -5 x2[t] - 44 y1[t] - 0.5 x1[t] y1[t] + Sin[5 t], 
      y1'[t] == y2[t], 
      y2'[t] == -3 y2[t] - 2 x2[t] + x1[t] y1[t]^2 + Cos[5 t], 
      x1[0] == 0.1, x2[0] == 0.02, y1[0] == 0.2, y2[0] == 0.01},
     {x1, x2, y1, y2}, {t, 0.1},
     Method -> Fehlberg45,
     StepMonitor :> (Sow[{++nstep, t}, "Step"];),
     "MethodMonitor" :> (Sow[NDSolve`Self, "Method"];),
     EvaluationMonitor :> (Sow[{++neval, nstep, t}, "Evaluation"];), 
     MaxStepFraction -> 1],    (* allow longer steps because of short interval *)
    {"Step", "Method", "Evaluation"}]
  ];
```

A presentations of the steps & evaluation times:

```
Grid[
 Join[
  {{"Step", "Evaluations", SpanFromLeft}},
  MapIndexed[Join[#2, #1] &,
   SplitBy[First@eval2, #[[2]] &][[All, All, 3]]]
  ],
 Alignment -> {Left, Automatic}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
methods2[[1, 1]] // Short
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
x1["Grid"] /. sol2
(*{{{0.},{0.0115275},{0.0280347},{0.0448688},{0.0620601},{0.0795363}, {0.0897682},{0.1}}}*)
```

Note that the default method `"LSODA"` does not use `"MethodMonitor"`.  Use `Trace[]` to see the `` NDSolve`LSODA `` method object it uses.

References:

- [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html) for `EvaluationMonitor` and `StepMonitor`.
- [The Design of the NDSolve Framework](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDesign.html) for `MethodMonitor`.
- [How to find out which method Mathematica selected?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145/how-to-find-out-which-method-mathematica-selected) for `MethodMonitor`
- [inspecting step size and order of $\tt NDSolve$](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102704/inspecting-step-size-and-order-of-tt-ndsolve), a similar question with another answer that uses `MethodMonitor`.
- `` NDSolve`Self `` represents a method object, which takes arguments that are discussed in the tutorial [NDSolve Method Plugin Framework](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolvePlugIns.html).
- [What's inside InterpolatingFunction[{{1., 4.}}, <>]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28337/whats-inside-interpolatingfunction1-4) for getting the `"Grid"` from `sol`.
- [Utility Packages for Numerical Differential Equation Solving](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolvePackages.html) for utilities such as `StepDataPlot[]` mentioned by @J.M. in a comment and getting the steps from the solution `sol`.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done by comparing the `Residual error` in both approaches. For this we need to set up the problem like this,

```
sys = {x1'[t] == x2[t], 
   x2'[t] == -5 x2[t] - 44 y1[t] - 0.5 x1[t] y1[t] + Sin[5 t], 
   y1'[t] == y2[t], 
   y2'[t] == -3 y2[t] - 2 x2[t] + x1[t] y1[t]^2 + Cos[5 t]};
residuals = sys /. Equal -> Subtract;
```

Now comparing the errors in both methods,

```
LogPlot[Join[Abs[residuals /. s1], Abs[residuals /. s2]] //Evaluate, {t, 0, 20}, 
PlotStyle -> {Red, Directive[Dashed, Green]},PlotLegends -> {"NDSolve", "Fehlberg45"},
Frame -> True,PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Checking the residual error in `Fehlberg45` only

```
LogPlot[Abs[residuals /. s2] // Evaluate, {t, 0, 20},PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.75],
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

**The idea behind this answer can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121824/calculating-the-error-in-the-solution-of-a-system-of-odes).**